# Tpm 2.0 takeownership not creating SRK

Tags: tpm

I am totally new and working on TPM 2.0 commands based on link below

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/index.html

I am trying to take ownership of TPM
in previous version I tried taking ownership it asks password for owner and SRK for TPM 2 its not asking

I have some questions on TPM

1. How to get EK and SRK using
   command
2. How to take ownership
3. How can i load/retrieve the certificate/key in/from TPM.
   Is there ant tool to interact with TPM as of now I am using **tpm2-tools**
   I googled a lot for it but I am confused wether I am right or not.

Any help many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would take ownership with [`tpm2_takeownership`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_takeownership.1.en.html). This gives you the hierarchy passwords you will need later on.

Then you would create the endorsement key with [`tpm2_createek`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_createek.1.en.html).

Then you would create the storage root key with [`tpm2_createprimary`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_createprimary.1.en.html), under `TPM_RH_OWNER`. Then you would make the SRK persistent with [`tpm2_evictcontrol`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_evictcontrol.1.en.html).

It is not clear what you mean by loading the certificate to the TPM... But if you mean signing a key certificate by a root CA and storing it in the TPM, then you would store it in NV RAM and make it persistent (again with `tpm2_evictcontrol`) at the appropriate index handle (for example, in accordance with the [`TCG guidance`](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG-TPM-v2.0-Provisioning-Guidance-Published-v1r1.pdf)).

NOTE: tpm2_takeownership [has been split](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/docs/CHANGELOG.md) into [tpm2_clear](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_clear.1.en.html) and [tpm2_changeauth](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_changeauth.1.en.html).

Comment: Thank you mnistic.. As above said i have, took ownership, created primary.. For certificate i have my own self signed CA certificate and client certificate .crt/.pem. How can i load those in TPM using NV storage(its default size is 2048).

Comment: First, you would define the index with [tpm_nvdefine](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_nvdefine.1.en.html) (you can make it the exact size of the certificate), then you would write to it with [tpm_nvwrite](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tpm2-tools/tpm2_nvwrite.1.en.html)

Comment: **PSA, `tpm2_takeownership` doesn't exist anymore.** It seems to have been replaced by [`tpm2_changeauth`](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_changeauth.1.md).

See https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/issues/2012.